# Why is Borel self-normalizing?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Given a reductive algebraic group $G$ over an algebraically closed field, why is its Borel subgroup $B$ self-normalizing? There is an answer on the site already, though **only** in $G=GL_n$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interested, this is explained in the Graduate Texts in Mathematics textbook on Algebraic groups, by Borel himself.